What class of matrices have efficient decompositions?
Suppose we have an arbitrary matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ where $N=2^n$. Now suppose that we can decompose $A$ into tensor products of the Pauli basis given by $A=\sum_{l=0}^Lc_lS_l$ where $S_l = \bigotimes_{k=0}^{\log N}\sigma_{r_k}$ for $r_k \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, $\, \sigma_{r_k} \in \{I,X,Y,Z\}$ and $c_l$ are complex coefficients. I am specifically interested in efficient decompositions defined by $L=\text{poly}(\log(N))$.
My questions are:

What class of matrices have efficient decompositions of this form? More specifically, suppose I pick a polynomial of order $P$ such that $L=\mathcal{O}(\log(N)^P)$, are there distinct structures that all matrices in this $P$-class must abide by?
If so, how can I learn about how these structures change with $P$?

Ultimately, I am interested in learning about efficient decompositions for an arbitrary native gate set (not just the Pauli basis as above). Given that, what area in literature is this topic contained in and what are the keywords that I should be searching for?
